# php help resolving error

Tags: php, captcha

Hello Im trying to make a form with a captca:

But everytime I submit it shows me that the captcha is wrong i dont know where is my mistake,
can you please look at the code and tell me ?

Here is the form: http://pastebin.com/yXx5APRD
look in the end.. for the input submit button...

Here is the captcha.php from where I get the image: http://pastebin.com/9hYnDBv4

view the comment below for the sending code pastebin

Comment: Here is the sending code: http://pastebin.com/cSe721Nt

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

http://sourceforge.net/projects/captcha/

Answer (score 1):

```
  $gjetja= $_SESSION["vercode"];
  if (!preg_match($gjetja,$vercode)) {
     $error_message .= '<strong>Incorrect verification code.</strong><br>'; 
  }
```

Try replace it with

```
  $gjetja= $_SESSION["vercode"];
  if ($gjetja !== trim($vercode)) {
     $error_message .= '<strong>Incorrect verification code.</strong><br>'; 
  }
```